# Sharing swf between teammates or hosting them elsewhere

Tags: git, flash-builder

I am building a proyect with someone else using Starling framework, but when he clones the proyect from Git he is unable to run/debug until the source path or SWF are changed manually to ones on his computer.

If he does that then when I clone to take the new changes I cannot run nor debug, is there any way to have universal source path or some service to host swf/folders and link them from there to the proyect?